# get odd and even part of number using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, digits

i have a 13 digit number and want extract odd and even part of this digit. i want to write truth checker function for EAN-13 barcode type that need calculate numbers of my digit.

so i have an digi like this: `1100050010004`
i want to get sum of odd and even part of that:

```
odd parts: 1+0+0+0+1+0+4
even parts: 1+0+5+0+0+0
```

i think that i must covert digit to array and get odd and even part of that array. this is true and best solution?

i use this method. is this good solution?

```
                var myArr = String(barcode).split("").map((barcode)=>{
                  return Number(barcode)
                });
                all_odd = 0;
                all_even = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
                    if (i % 2 === 0) all_odd += myArr[i];
                    else all_even += myArr[i];
                }
```

Comment: convert to string then array using [...num] or split. then simply loop

Comment: @cmgchess I'm exactly use this method. i just need to know that is a perfect & perfional solution or can we use better solution for this.

Comment: you can shorten the code with es6 syntax if that's you are wondering

Comment: btw why are you adding to odd if index is divisible by 2

Comment: @cmgchess `i` count from zero and i=2 is third number of my digit so even part of array is odd part of string

Comment: i can give you a one liner but the logic is essentially the same using some es6 features to shorten stuff

Comment: *or can we use better solution for this* - see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Ebadghafoory btw even in your implementatioin you don't have to do the map. you can parse to number inside the for loop. so it doesn't go through the whole array an extra time

Comment: If you believe that the code works correctly, consider presenting your work (with its unit tests) in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".

Answer (score 0):

You can define a helper function that sum odd or even digits using `filter` and `reduce`

```js
const sumOddOrEven = (num, isEven) => [...String(num)]
  .filter((_, i) => i % 2 === isEven)
  .reduce((acc, val) => acc + (+val), 0);


const num = 1100050010004;
const odd = sumOddOrEven(num, 0);
const even = sumOddOrEven(num, 1);

console.log(`Odd sum: ${odd}`);
console.log(`Even sum: ${even}`);
```